# cannot read property style, error on different page

Tags: javascript

once again im not sure where to go with this...i know its very basic but im having a hard time spotting it. im trying to hide several ids, and it works, except it gives me an error... :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null , this only appears on pages where the function isnt on..

```
function new1()
{ var news = ["1","2","3","4"];
    for (var i = 0; i<news.length; i++) 
    {
var s =document.getElementById("news"+news[i]).style.display = "none";
     }
}
```

thanks in advance, i can supply the xhtml if needed, its just several divs named news1,new2, my main concern is that the error is preventing some other scripts from working.
thanks in advance =]

```
<a  onclick="show1()" href="#"><h3>Spice Girls premiere new song</h3></a><div id="news1">
            <p class="news" > <em>Headlines (Friendship Never Ends)</em> is the first new single from the reformed girl band since 2000 and is the official Children In Need track for 2007.</p>

            <p class="news">Geri Halliwell, Victoria Beckham, Melanie Brown, Melanie Chisholm and Emma Bunton have regrouped to promote a new Spice Girls' greatest hits album and an upcoming world tour.  <a href="#">more ...</a></p></div>
            </div>
        <div id="story2">
            <a  onclick="show2()"  href="#"><h3>Jay-Z defends Nas album title</h3></a><div id="news2">
            <p class="news">Hip-hop mogul Jay-Z has defended Nas' decision to name his new album <span>N**ger</span>, but insists the naming of the record is "misguided".</p>

            <p class="news">Jay-Z - real name Shawn Carter - is releasing the LP under his label Island Def Jam Music Group, but admits he is not fond of its title.  <a href="#">more ...</a></p></div>
        </div>
        <div id="story3">
            <a  onclick="show3()" href="#"><h3>Winehouse defends MTV EMAs performance</h3></a><div id="new3">
            <p class="news" id="news3">Amy Winehouse has defended her performance at Thursday's MTV European Music Awards - citing exhaustion for her bizarre behaviour. <a href="#">more ...</a></p></div>
```

Comment: can you plz provide your html..and i dont understand why you take var s?? no need to take var s

Comment: How is you JS function actually invoked?

Comment: window.onload = function() 
{ disable();
 review(); 
 new1();
}

its effecting some of my other onload functions..due to the error (i think)

Comment: That's ok, I have provided an answer you can look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is fine with elements in indexes 0, 1 and 2 but looking to the final element which will be the id ***news4***, the JS call will throw an error since there is no DOM element with that id.

So remove the last entry in your ids array:

```
function new1() { 
    var news = ["1","2","3","4"];
    for (var i = 0; i<news.length; i++) 
    {
        var newsElement = document.getElementById("news"+news[i]);
        if (newsElement != null) 
        { 
            newsElement.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: um, about that there is a news 4, it appears i didnt select it during the paste onto stackoverflow :o

Comment: Then you have to look at @Jack answer. Check wether the element exists before you try to give it a new diplay style.
I update my answer.

Comment: Hello, i tried code and cleaned up a bit, it works like a charm, thank you =] , especially for going thru it.
OMG I CAN UPVOTE PEOPLE NOW YESSSSSSSSSSSSS

Comment: Glad to be in help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery. Nice, simple and cross browser:

```
function new1()
{ 
    var news = ["1","2","3","4"];
    for (var i = 0; i<news.length; i++) 
    {
      $('#news' + news[i]).hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: i didnt downvote... sadly i dont  have enough to upvote either =c